# Box API Refresh Token Expiring after 1 hour(BOX)

Tags: box

I am using box API.
through Authentication i got **Access Token(AT)** and **Refresh Token(RT)**.
After 1 hour **AT** is expired. Now i am requesting to server with current  **RT**

**Request:-** 
Post 
https://api.box.com/oauth2/token 
Params :-  
1) grant_type 
2) client_id 
3) client_secret 
4) refersh_token

Actual result is like this 
{
access_token:**new AT**
refersh_token:**new RT**
.....
.....
}

but my result is 
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "Refresh token has expired"
}

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If your Refresh Token is ever expired, you must get a new Refresh Token by starting the OAuth login flow from the beginning.

Starting with step 2 here:
https://developer.box.com/v2.0/docs/oauth-20#section-2-the-first-leg

Make sure that your code listens for the "401 Unauthorized" response from the API and saves the new Refresh Token back to wherever you are initializing your code from.